# Django admin search for non existing returns all items

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have the following model:

```
class FrontendUser(models.Model):

    CREDIT_RANGE = range(100, 199)

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'backoffice'
        db_table = 'users'

    uid = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    mail = models.CharField(max_length=254)
    created = models.IntegerField()
    login = models.IntegerField()
```

With the following admin interface:

```
class FrontendUserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ['mail', 'uid', 'login']
    list_display = ['customer_link', 'customer_email',  'mail',  'created_on',
                    'last_login_on', 'uid']
    readonly_fields = ['uid', 'created_on', 'login','created' ]
    actions = None

    def created_on(self, frontend_user):
        return datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(frontend_user.created)

    def last_login_on(self, frontend_user):
        return datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(frontend_user.login) if frontend_user.login else 'Never'

    def get_changelist(self, request, **kwargs):
        return CustomChangeList

    def customer_email(self, frontend_user):
        return u'<a href="/backoffice/frontenduser/%s">%s</a>' % (frontend_user.uid, frontend_user.mail)

    def customer_link(self, frontend_user):
        if frontend_user.uid != -1:
            return u'<a href="/customer/view/%s">%s</a>' % (frontend_user.uid, frontend_user.mail)
        else:
            return u'<a href="/customer/view/%s?mail_addr=%s">DOES NOT EXIST - %s</a>' % (frontend_user.uid, frontend_user.mail, frontend_user.mail)

    def has_add_permission(self, request):
        return False

    customer_link.allow_tags = True
    customer_email.allow_tags = True

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(FrontendUserAdmin, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.list_display_links = (None, )
```

When I search for a non existing email in search field, I *usually* get no result. 
Except when I look for some special email (I rather not put this email here, it's belongs to a customer), I get ALL the **59024** users in the database.

The email is 31 Chars long

```
 verylongemailproblem@gmail.com
```

It's enough the I change one character in the email, and then Django won't find any user like this (as expected). I also checked the database with the following queries directly:

```
select * from users where mail like 'verylongemailproblem@gmail.com';
select * from users where login like 'verylongemailproblem@gmail.com';
select * from users where uid like 'verylongemailproblem@gmail.com';
```

All of the above queries return no user.

#### update:

Django does the following queries:

```
(0.000) SELECT "django_session"."session_key", "django_session"."session_data", "django_session"."expire_date" FROM "django_session" WH
ERE ("django_session"."session_key" = r3fdvb8kn2ub6blbyqpfziq017yddhpm  AND "django_session"."expire_date" > 2014-01-29 11:09:46.454778
 ); args=('r3fdvb8kn2ub6blbyqpfziq017yddhpm', u'2014-01-29 11:09:46.454778')
(0.000) SELECT "auth_user"."id", "auth_user"."password", "auth_user"."last_login", "auth_user"."is_superuser", "auth_user"."username", 
"auth_user"."first_name", "auth_user"."last_name", "auth_user"."email", "auth_user"."is_staff", "auth_user"."is_active", "auth_user"."d
ate_joined" FROM "auth_user" WHERE "auth_user"."id" = 1 ; args=(1,)
(0.057) SELECT `company_payment_item`.`cpid`, `company_payment_item`.`coid`, `company_payment_item`.`mail`, `company_payment_item`.`amount`
, `company_payment_item`.`package`, `company_payment_item`.`status`, `company_payment_item`.`timestamp`, `company_payment_item`.`vin`, `car
fax_payment_item`.`report_ref` FROM `company_payment_item` WHERE (`company_payment_item`.`coid` = 'verylongemailproble@gmail.com'  OR `c
arfax_payment_item`.`mail` = 'verylongemailproble@gmail.com' ); args=(u'verylongemailproble@gmail.com', u'verylongemailproble@gmail.
com')
(0.133) SELECT `users`.`uid`, `users`.`mail`, `users`.`created`, `users`.`login` FROM `users` WHERE ((`users`.`mail` LIKE '%verylongemailproblem@gmail.com%'  
OR `users`.`uid` LIKE '%verylongemailproble@gmail.com%'  OR `users`.`login` LIKE '%verylongemailproble@gmail.c
om%' ) OR `users`.`mail` = 'verylongemailproble@gmail.com' ) ORDER BY `users`.`uid` DESC; args=(u'%verylongemailproble@gmail.com%', u
'%verylongemailproble@gmail.com%', u'%verylongemailproble@gmail.com%', u'verylongemailproble@gmail.com')
(1.593) SELECT `users`.`uid`, `users`.`mail`, `users`.`created`, `users`.`login` FROM `users` ORDER BY `users`.`uid` DESC; args=()
(0.007) SELECT `backend_transaction`.`id`, `backend_transaction`.`t_ref_id`, `backend_transaction`.`account_id`, `backend_transaction`.
`sub_account_id`, `backend_transaction`.`role`, `backend_transaction`.`t_type`, `backend_transaction`.`requester_id`, `backend_transact
ion`.`condition_id`, `backend_transaction`.`rcresult_id`, `backend_transaction`.`report_id`, `backend_transaction`.`ext_t_ref`, `backen
d_transaction`.`qty`, `backend_transaction`.`expires_on`, `backend_transaction`.`created`, `backend_transaction`.`asset_id` FROM `backe
nd_transaction` WHERE `backend_transaction`.`t_ref_id` = 'verylongemailproble@gmail.com' ; args=(u'verylongemailproble@gmail.com',)
(0.026) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `users`; args=()
```

- So the question is why am I getting all 59024 entries in the table when I search Django for that database?
- Can some offer some insight how to solve the problem?

Comment: What is the SQL query executed by Django ?

Comment: @Adrien, I have no clue ... It's buried deep somewhere inside Django's code

Comment: django-debug-toolbar should display the query in the browser as you execute the search.

Comment: @Adrien, I put the query in the update ...

Comment: Does the toolbar show you from where (1.593) is run ?

Comment: @Adrien, I am sorry, I didn't use the tool bar. I copied the queries from the console I used logging. What do you mean by where?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(0.133) is the query looking for the email you mentioned.
(1.593) is selecting all users.

Either the first is returning all results, in which case one of mail, uid or login is in fact holding verylongemailproble@gmail.com as a substring for every record.
Or FrontendUserAdmin is returning every record for some other reason.

In the second case, maybe django-debug-toolbar will show where this query was ran inside django, that will help you dig through the code.

Investigate whichever sounds more likely or easier to you.

Comment: I would execute the first one manually, seems more likely to me as no email appears in the code.

Comment: This seems to me like a weird bug in Django 1.5.1, the user now exists in my DB, so things work as expected again.